# What to do with the [customer-account-data] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

A user recently created the [customer-account-data](/questions/tagged/customer-account-data) tag, and has been clogging up the Suggested Edit queue with them (30+ edits and counting).

It looks like each of these questions already has the [intuit-partner-platform](/questions/tagged/intuit-partner-platform) tag, although a number of the questions also include the term "AggCat".

I'm no intuit-partner-platform expert, but I'm not 100% sure that these tag edits are all valid.  Can someone confirm this?

Also, to me, [customer-account-data](/questions/tagged/customer-account-data) sounds extremely vague and meta ... if there is some merit to this tag, could there be a better tag name?

Comment: From the Tag Wiki: *"The Customer Account Data API is part of the Intuit Partner Platform that provides developers access to end-user financial account and transactional information."*

Comment: @RobertHarvey Seems like it should be called the `customer-account-data-api` tag

Comment: Yeah, I read the tag wiki.  My point is, with a name like "customer-account-data", it sounds like the take could easily be misinterpreted.  Also, it seems like most tagged questions prefer the prhase **AggCat**.  I do like the idea of [customer-account-data-api].

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Seems sensible to me.  Let me pull out my handy tag renaming too.  Oh, wait. ***I don't have one.***

Comment: @RobertHarvey We can't rename tags? Wha?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Sure you can, if you want to go through all 31 posts.

Comment: Yeah, going through all 31 posts is probably pointless -- the user is on a spree and has made 90 suggestions in the past day.  If you edit the questions, the old tag will still exist, and we'll just get to play catch-up when the user most likely keeps using the old tag.

Comment: Well, we could add a synonym to force the old usage to the new one.

Comment: <sheepish> Oh yeah, tag synonyms... forgot about those... </sheepish>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I changed one of the questions' tags to [customer-account-data-api], added a synonym, reversed it, and did a merge.  I always get a bit nervous when I try this; caching makes the system behavior a bit squirrely after such a change, and it did bork the tag wiki, but it's done.

All of the questions now have the tag [customer-account-data-api](/questions/tagged/customer-account-data-api), and [customer-account-data] is synonymized to it, so if the user decides to do any more suggested edits, he'll be forced to use the new tag.