# Can we have a new "mass edits" review queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, suggested-edits

I have seen so many times when one person makes hundreds and hundreds of small maybe pointless maybe helpful edits. For example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2140489/manas-mukherjee?tab=activity&sort=revisions) and it's [meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193240/what-to-do-with-the-customer-account-data-tag). Because people often come and go in the review queue, these kinds of things are never even recognized most of the time. While I'm not saying that *this* example is neccisarily a bad edit, I still think that all of these mass edits should be put up to some kind of human review *as a unit*, not as many individual reviews.

---

So, here's my suggestion. When, for example, the system sees a certain number of edits that satisfy some of these basic checks and are from the same user, eg:

- Identical edit message
- Added the same tag to a question with a different tag many times
- Changed one word to one other word many times (people search for misspellings and replace one)
- Add the same tag hundreds of times
- Etc.

When a set of edits matches these, the system will put the set (a list of the suggested edits, the user suggesting them, and a highlight on what criteria it met and how) into a review queue with a (relatively) high rep barrier, enough that it can mostly be used by users who know how to sort out these tricky situations.

The review could include these actions:
 - Ignore: These edits are part of a tag cleanup, or are legitimate and *not* to minor
 - Meta: Create a meta discussion about them (link to meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)
 - Some sort of Reject: I have no idea what this would do, but I'm sure that the community has some ideas ;)

## So...

Do you think this is necessary?

If so, what should the criteria and reject action be?

Comment: In terms of triggers, you don't really need much more than more than X edits made by a single user in less than Y period of time.  Trying to use the triggers that you're describing is harder and less reliable.

Comment: I think these sprees are rare enough occurrence and require a high enough understanding of what is or is not acceptable that this maybe shouldn't be anything like a regular queue at all. I think it's not a bad idea to have a system automatically checking for patterns like this after each edit. But upon being triggered (either based off a set of rules or based off just edit rate as @Servy proposed), it should just submit an automatic moderator attention flag (though there might have to be some safeguard built in to prevent the flag from repeatedly being sent for the same user in one session).